# How to run Java RMI projects in Netbeans 7.0?

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi

I am facing trouble to develop a RMI application in Netbeans 7.0. Is there anyway to start registry , create stubs and complete a simple project in netbeans? A simple description will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [RMI tutorial](http://littletutorials.com/2008/07/14/the-10-minutes-getting-started-with-rmi-tutorial/), it'll show you how to work with RMI without having to create stubs.

Answer (score 1):

Stub creation is not needed in recent versions of java, but there is an <rmic> ant task that you can add to your build.xml file. The registry can be started programatically, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port)`